# Deleting a Node using an ArrayList in java

Tags: java, xml, dom

I have a method that retrieves all of the Nodes of an XML file, and I need to delete a certain Node (without knowing its name, parent, or anything).  All I have is this `ArrayList` of Nodes that contains all of the Nodes inside "Ex2.xml", but the node still appears in the XML file when I try to delete it using:

`BN2.get(5).getParentNode().removeChild(BN2.get(5));`

**Note:** BN2 is the `ArrayList` that contains the nodes.

```
File xmlFile = new File("Ex2.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder;
dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

BN2.get(5).getParentNode().removeChild(BN2.get(5));

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();

DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(doc);

StreamResult streamResult = new StreamResult(new File("Ex2.xml"));

transformer.transform(domSource, streamResult);
```

XmL file: the  is not showing although it is written here

```
<a>
  <b>
    <s>
        <e>AAA</e>
        <e>BBB</e>
        <e>CCC</e>
    </s>
    <d>
        <v>whatever</v>
        <f>
        </f>
    </d>
</b>
```

Comment: You're reading a file in a `doc` variable, delete some element from a completely unrelated list `BN2`, then write the doc to the file. Why would that remove anything from the document. Where does `BN2` come from?

Comment: Can you add the code that fill BN2? and maybe an extract of the xml?

Comment: BN2 is being filled by a class that uses the same XML file and here is the XML File @AbbéRésina 

JB well the thing is if i need to delete a node from an XML file that i dont know anything about